# Add 30 days to a Current date - JS

Tags: javascript, datejs

I want to add 30 days to current date and get in a format.

Im confused to add a 30 to a date and get new.

Its pure JS Solution needed.

Format : June 10, 2017

Comment: Please always first use the Search box of this site (or even Google), as I typed `javascript add days` and found this duplicate right away. And if you need it formatted, just search for `javascript format date`.

Comment: Thanks @PeterB, Its was a urgent one.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(); // Now
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30); // Set now + 30 days as the new date
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked for me well.

Comment: ty that works for me. whoever says its not working for them needs to make sure he's adding a numeric value, string will evaluate wrong date.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you are using datejs?

```
var newDate = Date.today().add(30).days();
```

Comment: Hey, you actually may be right. The questions tag suggests `datejs` so this is the answer. Although the tag probably wasn't intentional

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
var yourDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 30;
console.log(yourDate.setDate(yourDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd));
```